# iOS: How do you plot points and draw lines

Tags: objective-c

Can someone show me an example on how to plot points and connect them in iOS objective C. Do I need to put CGPoint's in an array or can we draw one point at a time? What we want to do is calculate the corresponding y value from x value and make a CGPoint and plot them, in a for loop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's not really about what language you are using, it's about what technology stack you are using. iOS? Mac? Then there are many options: 3rd party library, Core Plot, Core Graphics (2D procedural drawing API), Open GL, Core Animation (2D/3D compositing and animation API) or even some combination of these.

The correct answer depends on what you are building, big picture.

As it stands I think the question is to broad to answer.

Comment: I believe we're using Core Graphics. We're programming iOS applications.

Comment: If you Google there are lots of examples, i.e. http://kalyanchakravarthy.net/blog/ios-drawing-using-coregraphics.html

Comment: Why are you using Core Graphics?